# An example of a function presented by Riemann in one of his paper

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory

I came across this function which Riemann has constructed in his paper 'On the representation of a function by a trigonometric series' to prove that a function that is dicontinuous in infinitely many points could be integrable.
he wrote:

> Since these functions have never been considered before, it is well to start
> from a particular example. Designate, for brevity, $(x)$ to be the excess of $x$
> over the closest integer, or if x lies in the middle between two (and thus the
> determination is ambiguous) the average of the two numbers $1/2$ and $-1/2$,
> hence zero.
> Furthermore, let $n$ be an integer and $p$ an odd integer, and form the series
> $$f(x) = (x) + (2x)/2 + (3x)/9 + \cdots $$
> It is easy to see that the series converges for each value of $x$. When the argument
> continuously decreases to $x$, as well as when it continuously increases
> to $x$, the value always approaches a fixed limit. Indeed, if $x = \frac{p}{2n}$ (where $p$
> and $n$ are relatively prime)
> $$
> f(x + 0) = f(x) - \frac{\pi^2}{16n^2}
> $$
> $$
> f(x - 0) = f(x) + \frac{\pi^2}{16n^2}
> $$
> in all other cases $f(x + 0) = f(x)$ and $f(x - 0) = f(x)$.

Could you please help me understand how he got to these results in detail? I found it puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

The German original can be seen here, 20 minutes read.
[Riemann Habil](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN309770033?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B21%5D%2C%22pan%22%3A%7B%22x%22%3A0.719%2C%22y%22%3A0.395%7D%2C%22view%22%3A%22info%22%2C%22zoom%22%3A0.695%7D)

The second term is denominator (2x)/4, of course.

So you deal with an integer periodic function with infinitely many jumps of bounded variation, something one calls today an extremely discontinous case of a Riemann summable function.

In Mathematica

```
    f[x_] = Sum[Mod[n x, 1]/n^2, {n, 1, 12}]
```

$$(x \bmod 1)+\frac{1}{4} ((2 x) \bmod 1)+\frac{1}{9} ((3 x) \bmod 1)+\frac{1}{16} ((4 x) \bmod 1)+\frac{1}{25} ((5 x) \bmod 1)+\frac{1}{36} ((6 x) \bmod 1)+\frac{1}{49} ((7 x) \bmod 1)+\frac{1}{64} ((8 x) \bmod 1)+\frac{1}{81} ((9 x) \bmod 1)+\frac{1}{100} ((10 x) \bmod 1)+\frac{1}{121} ((11 x) \bmod 1)+\frac{1}{144} ((12 x) \bmod 1)$$

```
     Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 7}, Ticks -> {Automatic, {0, Pi/2}}]
```

With this example Riemann decided the 100 years old dispute between Euler, Lagrange, Bernoulli and Fourier about the range in function spaces of Fourier series and touched the integrability question of noncontinuous functions, resolved by Lebesgue.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, actually I would like to know how he arrived at the limit {pi^2}/{16n^2}